# how to use Backbone.js, but in the NO-RESTful way?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web

I'm now a front-end developer, and I have a project which is fine to use BackboneJS, and the server-side is written by others.  Is there anyone who can tell me how to override delete, update, add, and so on in a not-RESTful way?  The server-side's URL may be like this:

- add: `www.domain.com/addBookById`
- remove: `www.domain.com/removeBookById`

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: *I'm now a front-end developer* ... **Uh-oh!**  Haha, just kidding ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Backbone uses [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to manage all communication with the server. There are two important things about `sync` for you; first of all, it looks like this:

> The method signature of **Backbone.sync** is `sync(method, model, [options])`
>
> - **method** – the CRUD method (`"create"`, `"read"`, `"update"`, or `"delete"`)
> - **model** – the model to be saved (or collection to be read)
> - **options** – success and error callbacks, and all other jQuery request options

and the second is that you can override `sync` on a per-model and per-collection basis. So you can add your own `sync` implementation to your model:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        //...
    },
    //...
});
```

If you look at `method` you can decide which URL to use and whether you're doing a GET, POST, ... request.  The `model` will tell you what data to send to the server. You'll want to merge `options` into the `$.ajax` options you want to use. Have a look at the standard implementation of `Backbone.sync`, it is pretty straight forward and should show you what you need to do: just replace the URL handling and drop some of the features you don't care about (such as `emulateHTTP` and `emulateJSON`).

Answer (score 3):

**The best option** in your case is plugin like [Backbone.service](http://mkuklis.github.io/backbone.service/). It is Backbone service for non restful or semi restful apis.

```
// define server targets / endpoints
var targets = {
  login: ["/login", "post"],
  signup: ["/signup", "post"],
  logout: ["/logout", "get"],
  search: "/search" // defaults to get
  resetPassword: ["/resetpassword", "post"],
  updateSettings: ["/updateSettings", "post"]
};

// standalone service
var service = new Backbone.Service({ url: "http://localhost:5000", targets: targets });

// extend backbone model
var User = Backbone.Model.extend(service);
```

You can use it like this:

```
var user = new User();
user.login({ username: 'bob', password: 'secret' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a modified Backbone.js ajax call:

```
var Forecast = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return "http://api.wunderground.com/api/7eaec3b21b154448/conditions/q/" + this.get( "zip" ) + ".json";
  },
  parse : function( data, xhr ) {
    var observation = data.current_observation;
    return {
      id: observation.display_location.zip,
      url: observation.icon_url,
      state: observation.display_location.state_name,
      zip: observation.display_location.zip,
      city: observation.display_location.city,
      temperature: observation.temp_f
    };
  }
});
```

From: [Elijah Manor's Intro to Backbone.JS](http://elijahmanor.github.com/talks/intro-to-backbonejs/index.html#/8/7)

Comment: my purpose is "In the traditional RESTful-style,"one resource to one url",but in my project,I need to consider "on resource to different url->/getxxbyxx,deletexxbyxx,"  I'm so confused!