# Backbone.js with non-RESTful servers save method

Tags: backbone.js

I'm starting to implement backbone.js on a new app, however, the API I'm using it is not kind of restful, so I want to know if I can still use some similar methods, for sample:

Let's say I have a trivial scenario where I need among other options to delete users, however each option has its own controller, so I trigger them like this:

```
fetch : FetchController.php
Update : DeleteController.php?data={'id':'x'}
```

So my view would look like this:

```
 var UserEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
     'submit .delete-form': 'deleteUser'
   },

   //.... other methods

   deleteUser: function(event) {
        //user is a instance of my User Collection
        this.user.destroy({
           //here is where I point my question
        });
   } 

 });
```

Let's say all my controllers are called via Post Method, so I don't have the change to send a Delete Method to destroy... my question is, can I create a own destroy method? or at least configure it to call an custom controller? so I can do the same to create and edit records?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can override [backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to use whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely use [$.ajax options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) override it with attributes `url`, `method` and `data`

```
model.fetch({
    url: 'FetchController.php'
});

model.destroy({
    url: 'DeleteController.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: "id=x"
});
```

You may also override `fetch` and `destroy` method inside your model to do not use this every time in views.

Or even override `Backbone.sync` method to support your backend services. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465645/how-to-use-backbone-js-but-in-the-no-restful-way) to related question.

Comment: Thanks a ton Eugene, that link was ver helpfull